# Conditional rendering doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I want to conditionally render an image in my react component like so: `{noTasks && <Image />}`
It works just fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome, even though Chrome also detects noTasks === true. What am I missing here?

The `<Image />` itself doesn't have any special styling or positioning

```js
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledImg = styled.img`
  width: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
`

const Image = () => <StyledImg src='/assets/toDo.webp' alt='a woman with a task planner' />

export default Image
```

```js
const ToDos = () => {
  const tasks = useSelector((state) => state.todos.items)
  const noTasks = useSelector((state) => state.todos.items.length === 0)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const trashCanIcon = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashAlt} />
  /* const editIcon = <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPen} /> */

  const onToggleIsComplete = (id) => {
    dispatch(todos.actions.toggleIsComplete(id))
  }

  return (
    <ContainerDiv>
      {noTasks && <Image />}
      {tasks.map((task) => (
        <StyledForm 
          key={task.id}
          category={task.category}
          completed={task.isComplete}
        >
          <ToDoLabel
            completed={task.isComplete} 
            htmlFor='completed'>{task.task}
          </ToDoLabel>
          <div>
            <input 
              id='completed'
              type='checkbox' 
              onChange={() => onToggleIsComplete(task.id)}
            />
            {/* <button >{editIcon}</button> */}
            <button onClick={() => dispatch(todos.actions.removeToDo(task.id))}>        {trashCanIcon}</button>
          </div>
          <StyledParagraph>{moment(task.newDate).format("D. MM. YYYY")}</StyledParagraph> 
        </StyledForm>
      ))}
    </ContainerDiv>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description it's possible that the issue is with the implementation of the `<Image />` component.

You could check the source of the page by using developer tools to find out how React renders the `ToDos` component (right click --> inspect on Chrome). Can you confirm whether you've already done this?

My guess is that it could be a styling issue where the content of `Image` component is rendered (there's an `img` tag in the source of the page), but styled in a way where it's not visible. It could for instance be positioned absolutely, which in some instances can cause differing behaviour between browsers.

It can also be caused by some implementation detail in the `<Image />` component. By providing a bit more context about the `<Image />` component, following helpers may have an easier time finding possible causes for your problem.

Comment: Hej Jokinen, great feedback. I edited my post and as you can see, there was no special styling involved. BUT I was playing around in the devtools a bit more and I found out, that width=80% isn't enough for chrome to render. I needed to give a specific width/height. So thanks for poking in the right direction!